# d3 tooltip different text depending on positive and negative value

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am wondering why doing the following is not possible:

```
div.text(function(d) {return " bought " + d.USD;})
```

It works fine for the either red or green circles earlier in the code:

```
  .style("fill", function(d) {if (d.USD <= 0) {return "green"} 
                      else      { return "red" };})
```

Here is the extract of my code responsible for drawing the circles and adding a tooltip:

```
// Draw circle around values

svg.selectAll("dot")

  .data(bitstamp_data)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("r", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(Math.abs(d.USD)) - 5; })
  .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
  .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.Price); })
  .style("fill-opacity", 0.7)
  .attr("stroke", "black")

// Show different colour depending on buying or selling USD based on positive or negative d.USD
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    if (d.USD <= 0) {return "green"} 
    else        { return "red" }
    ;})

// Tooltip section
  .on("mouseover", function(d) {
    div.transition()
      .duration(400)
      .style("opacity", .9);

    div.text(function(d) {return " bought " + d.USD
              ;})

      .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 15) + "px")
  .attr("stroke", "black")
      .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");

    })
```

Comment: You should be able to just write: `div.text(" bought " + d.USD)`

Comment: What do you mean when you say that it is not possible?

Comment: Eventually, I want to do the same if condition for the div.text, depending on if the value is positive or negative. It works using nemesv solution but I cannot implement a condition this way. What I mean by not possible is that the tooltip does not appear anymore when I write div.text(function(d) etc....